# Identify a number inside a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to identify a particular element inside a div array. Suppose there is an array having 5 elements from 1 to 5. These elements 1 to 5 are stored inside a div array element. My requirement is, if I click on number 1, that element should get highlighted. Is there any function which can identify if a number inside a div array element is selected? Is this functionality possible with JavaScript?

What I tried was:

//structure to create a div as an array of date elements

My code after applying information provided by @Tinh:
$('.calendar').click(function(event){
        var input = $("#info1");

```
 document.getElementById("info1").innerHTML=document.getElementById("info1").innerHTML + event.target.innerText + ",";
```

});

where "info1" is the id denoted to a text area where all dates should get entered as soon as any date is clicked inside the calendar.

Now my code is working fine now. Thanks to all!

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a code example of what this “div array” is (see [mre]). Have you tried event delegation using `addEventListener`?

Comment: `a div array element`?? Do you mean an Array of div elements?

Comment: @MEENAL SAXENA20 can you please elaborate more and mention your code for better understanding.

Comment: Hi Bravo, yes it is an array of div elements, actually div is a calendar showing dates of the month. <div class="calendar"></div> Values of the div ( 1,2,...) are stored inside an array 'days'.

Comment: Hello Simon, actually div stores calendar dates 1,2,... <div class="classname"></div> My requirement is whenever I click on any date inside this div it should get highlighted. Thank you!

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar, I need to highlight a date when selected in a dynamic calendar. For creating this dynamic calendar, I am storing the dates inside a div which is an array of date elements <div class="calendar"></div> Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Simon, I have updated the question along with the solution. The code is working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example I whipped up, perhaps it will give you a starting point for detecting clicks.

**Please also read the references I linked to get a full-rounded understanding of how and why this works.**

Javascript / jQuery version:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');
loadNumbers(); 

function loadNumbers() {
  array.forEach(function(value) {    
      $myDiv.append('<div>' + array[value - 1] + '</div>')
  });
}

$($myDiv).on('click', function(e){
      var elementClicked = e.target;
      $(elementClicked).text('The number ' + $(elementClicked).text() + ' was clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Pure Javascript version:

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var innerElementClicked = e.target;
    innerElementClicked.innerText = 'I was clicked';
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

[jQuery | click() with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-click-with-examples/)

[jQuery .append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

[JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

[JavaScript Function Call](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp)

[JavaScript Array forEach() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

Comment: The question doesn’t mention jQuery at all.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a click event in pure JS.

Comment: Upvoted for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Demo here :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="parent">
  <div>DIV NUMBER 1</div>
  <div>DIV NUMBER 2</div>
  <div>DIV NUMBER 3</div>
  <div>DIV NUMBER 4</div>
  <div>DIV NUMBER 5</div>
<div>

<script>
 $('#parent').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(event.target.innerText);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It requires Jquery to run. So remember to add [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) to your HTML code.
For example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR without Jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="parent">
  <div onclick="click_element(this)">DIV NUMBER 1</div>
  <div onclick="click_element(this)">DIV NUMBER 2</div>
  <div onclick="click_element(this)">DIV NUMBER 3</div>
  <div onclick="click_element(this)">DIV NUMBER 4</div>
  <div onclick="click_element(this)">DIV NUMBER 5</div>
<div>

<script>
 function click_element(e){
     alert(e.innerText);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your effort!

Comment: Thank you @Tinh for your reply! It is useful, I am trying to modify my code using the information you have provided. Thanks a lot!